# build static libcurl lib using WinSSL on windows

Tags: c++, windows, ssl, curl, libcurl

I want to create static libcurl.lib with WinSSl.
I built libcurl.lib on windows with VC++ using the command:
"nmake /f makefile.vc RTLIBCFG=static ENABLE_WINSSL=yes mode=static MACHINE=x64 VC=17"

it created a lib inside the directory:
"libcurl-vc17-x64-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl"
"libcurl-vc17-x64-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib" (I tried them both)

after that I created a new dll project that will link with this lib (using linker-input-libcurl.lib)

after I created my dll and inspect it using CFF explorer I can see it has libcurl.dll in its import directories which means it wasnt built staticly at all.

what am I missing here?

Comment: I would recommend asking on the curl-library list instead. Is `MODE` perhaps case sensitive so you should use uppercase?

Comment: its not case sensitive, I tried both ways and got the same result. I couldn't find anything about this phenomenon on the libcurl site but I posted the same question over there too

Comment: Solved it. I used the visual studio command prompt instead of the visual c++ one and everything works just fine